# How to get MenuItems from Different Android application

Tags: android

I have called "Contacts" app's EditContactActivity from MyApplication. I want to get Contextmenuitems ie ( "Send sms" , "call" , "Edit" , etc ) as menus. So i can use this menu in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The source code to Android is at http://source.android.com. Copy whatever you like, respecting copyright and license terms.